# TRUNC(date) with subquery in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a IF condition which checks the dates in the subquery as shown below

```
IF (TRUNC(lv_d_itr) IN
(SELECT next_day(TRUNC(to_date('01-01-17','dd-mm-yy'),'YYYY') + 14*(level-1), 'WED' )+7
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 26)) THEN
```

Why am i getting the below error? usage is wrong?

```
PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
```

What could be the alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this in different ways, a simple one could be something like:

```
declare
  n number;
begin
    select count(1)
    into n
     from
        (       
         SELECT next_day(TRUNC(to_date('01-01-17','dd-mm-yy'),'YYYY') + 14*(level-1), 'MER' )+7 as x
         FROM dual
         CONNECT BY level <= 26
        )
     where x = TRUNC(lv_d_itr);
    if n > 0
      then ...
    end if;
    ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksej. So i should check like `IF 1 = *above mentioned code* `? am i right?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a sub-query in a pl/sql `IF` statement:

```
BEGIN
  IF 'X' IN ( SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL ) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'X' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Will error with `PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context`

You can refactor it to get the same effect:

```
DECLARE
  p_exists NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN 'X' IN ( SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL )
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END
  INTO   p_exists
  FROM   DUAL;

  IF p_exists = 1 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'X' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Even with `CASE` statement it is giving same error.